# Parse Java tree structure while nodes can contain ArrayList's

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have started an implementation of a Java tree structure:

```
Root(Key, Value) --> NODE1(Key, Value)
                 --> NODE2(Key, Value)
                 --> NODE3(Key, Value) --> NODE4(Key, Value)
                                       --> NODE5(Key, Value)
                                       --> ...
```

So here you can see that the root node can contain an undefined number of children and this children can contain also an undefined number of children.
So now my question is, how to find `NODE5` with only given the key and starting at the root node?

(Remember: This tree can be really big!)

Comment: Try using recursion... Will make searching very easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to walk through the tree and check every child. This could be done via recursion. Try something similar like this:

```
public Node getNode(Key key, List<Node> children) {
    if (children != null) {
        for (Node child : children) {
            if (child.getKey().equals(key)) {
                return child;
            } else {
                return getNode(key, child.getChildren());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is unsorted you have to look in the whole tree. There are common ways how to do this. It is called ([traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)). There are 3 ways (Pre/In/Post order). Normaly you implement such behavior as a recursive function.